# Como resolvo isto: Field error in object 'fatura' on field 'demandaPontaKW': rejected value [kWh: 1.582,05];

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf, maskmoney

Bom dia pessoal, estou com uma dúvida referente a persistência de dados utilizando máscara do maskMoney, na minha classe os atributos estão como double e na minha view quando utilizo a máscara é enviado uma string, como posso resolver isso de uma forma que não precise parar de usar a máscara e os dados consigam ser persistidos normalmente? Abaixo segue minha view, Classe e o jquery.

HTML:

```
     <form th:action="cadastrar" method="post" th:object="${fatura}">
                       

 <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12">
   <label for="demandaPonta">Demanda Ponta:</label>
 <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="demandaPonta" autocomplete="off" th:field="*{demandaPontaKW}" placeholder="kWh: 0,00">
   </div>

  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12">
   <label for="demandaForaPonta">Demanda Fora Ponta:</label>
   <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="demandaForaPonta" autocomplete="off" th:field="*{demandaForaPontaKW}" placeholder="kWh: 0,00">
 </div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $('#demandaPonta').maskMoney({
      prefix: 'kWh: ',
      allowNegative: false,
      thousands: '.', decimal: ',',
      affixesStay: true
                    });

      $('#demandaForaPonta').maskMoney({
       prefix: 'kWh: ',
       allowNegative: false,
       thousands: '.', decimal: ',',
       affixesStay: true
                    });
```

Classe:

```
@Entity
```

public class Fatura {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "demanda_ponta_kw")
private Double demandaPontaKW;

@Column(name = "demanda_fora_ponta_kw")
private Double demandaForaPontaKW;
```

}

*Obs: apenas frizando que os métodos de acesso e HashCode and Equals estão criados normal na classe coloquei a parte do código que realmente importa.*

Answer (score -3):

Como na sua entidade você utiliza o tipo Double para demandaPontaKW logo o spring vai rejeitar o tipo string "kWh: 1.582,05" com a mensagem de erro informada.
Na sua classe controller ou service da sua aplicação você precisa primeiro converter de String para Double, retirando "kWh: " e alterando a formatação numérica para o padrão, para isso use a lógica abaixo:

```
String consumoPonta = "kWh: 1.582,05";
String valor_consumoPonta = consumoPonta.substring(5).replace(".", "").replace(",", ".");
double valorDouble_consumoPonta = Double.parseDouble(valor_consumoPonta);
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", Double.valueOf(valorDouble_consumoPonta)));
```